# Combine lambdas with operators

Tags: c++

I want to know if it is possible to chain a bunch of lambdas so that I can use them all at once, something like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
auto f1 = [](int i){return i == 1;};
auto f2 = [](int i){return i == 2;};

// What template type can I use for logical_or ?
auto f = combine(std::logical_or, f1, f2); 

vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), f), vec.end());
```

So far I was thinking something like this:

```
template <typename OP, typename T>
T combine(const OP& op, const T& t1, const T& t2) {
    return t1 op t2;
}

template <typename OP, typename T, typename... Ts>
T combine(const OP& op, const T& t1, const T& t2, const Ts&... ts) {
    return t1 op t2 op combine(op, ts...);
}
```

But `lambda || lambda` doesn't make sense.
Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: You need to call the lambdas with arguments: `op(t1(arg), t2(arg))`

Comment: how about `auto f = [&](int i) { return f1(i) || f2(i); };` ?

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks the code `vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), f), vec.end());` is problematic? The outer `erase` call seems to be useless.

Comment: @Lingxi: Look at [Erase-Remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Comment: @Jarod42: Oh. My bad.

Comment: I want to be able to chain multiple lambdas, not just 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might create class to do the job:

```
template <typename ... Fs>
struct AnyOf
{
public:
    AnyOf(Fs... fs) : fs(fs...) {};

    template <typename ...Ts>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Ts&&... args) const
    {
        return call(std::index_sequence_for<Fs...>(), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

private:
    template <std::size_t ...Is, typename ...Ts>
    decltype(auto) call(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&... args) const
    {
        return (... || std::get<Is>(fs)(args...));
    }
private:
    std::tuple<Fs...> fs;
};
```

With usage:

```
auto f = AnyOf(f1, f2); // C++17 way.
                        //previously, template function `MakeAnyOf` should be implemented
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fb5bdba3b467fd6)

Comment: That looks very cool!! The fold statement in the `call` function is C++17 only right? Is it possible to do something like that in C++14?

Comment: Yes it is fold expression, you can do similar code using c++14 only but it is more verbose (and extra difficulty is to respect short-circuit evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class F>
struct logical_f;
template<class F>
logical_f<F> logical( F f ){
  return std::move(f);
}
template<class F>
struct logical_f:F{
  logical_f(F in):F(std::move(in)){}
  template<class O>
  friend auto operator||( logical_f self, logical_f<O> const& o ) {
    auto r = [lhs=std::move(self.f), rhs=o.f](auto&&...args)->bool{
      return lhs(args...)||rhs(args...);
    };
    return logical(std::move(r));
};
```

now you can do:

```
auto f = logical(f1) || logical(f2);
```

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can fold over `||`; prior to that you can use hand written functions that do the folding.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this functional one-liner (it use fold expression so it's `c++17`)

```
auto any_combiner = [](auto&& ...fs){return [=](auto&& ...params){return (fs(params...) ||...);};}; 
auto any = any_combiner(f1,f2);
```

[Wandbox example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eIVTMnp2HCNwmC7R)

---

or you can simply use `std::any_of` for `||` (and `std::all_of` for `&&`), and it's `c++11`

```
vector<function<bool(int)>> fs = {f1,f2};
auto any = [&](int i){return std::any_of(fs.begin(),fs.end(),[i](function<bool(int)>&f){return f(i);});};
```

---

or what's wrong with plain old `for`, it so simple! (basically std::any_of)

```
vector<function<bool(int)>> fs = {f1,f2};
auto any = [&](int i){
    for(auto& f:fs)
        if(f(i))
            return true;
    return false;
};
```